# Store array of objects into SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

What would happen if i were to store a custom Object like this,

```
public MyObject myobj = new MyObj();
```

Into an SQL prepared statement like so:

```
ps.setArray(1, arrayofmyobjects);
```

Would the objects inside the array be intact when I retrieved them from the database?

Comment: So you're using SQLite or MySQL? You should also try and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert object into blob and save to database. but sqlite has limited to store such data types. if you are using mySQL, it will be fine